# node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bcrypt

When I install [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) module for my hapi js project it is not installed and it's shows something like

> `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

I tried to install by running;

```
npm i node-pre-gyp
```

but it's not working.

---

**Error:**

> ```
> PS C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\loginLogout> npm i bcrypt
>
> > bcrypt@3.0.6 install C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authenticatin\node_modules\bcrypt
>
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.10.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
> gyp ERR! find VS 
> gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
> gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
> gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.3.29411.108) found at:
> gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
> gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
> gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
> gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
> gyp ERR! find VS - not found
> gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
> gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
> gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
> gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
> gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:344:14)
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:365:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
> gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\safras\\Desktop\\authentication\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\safras\\Desktop\\authentication\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" 
> "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt
> gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
> gyp ERR! not ok 
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
> --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding
> --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
> node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\safras\\Desktop\\authentication\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
> Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
> --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding
> --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
> npm WARN hapi-auth-basic@5.0.0 requires a peer of hapi@>=17.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN authentication@1.0.0 No description
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\safras\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-18T06_32_05_741Z-debug.log
> PS C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\loginLogout> npm i node-pre-gyp
> npm WARN hapi-auth-basic@5.0.0 requires a peer of hapi@>=17.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN authentication@1.0.0 No description
> npm WARN authentication@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> + node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
> added 4 packages from 8 contributors, removed 1 package and audited 244 packages in 2.057s
> found 0 vulnerabilities
>
> PS C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\loginLogout> @hapi/hapi -v
> At line:1 char:7
> + @hapi/hapi -v
> +       ~
> PS C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\loginLogout> npm install -g node-gyp
> C:\Users\safras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-gyp -> C:\Users\safras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> + node-gyp@6.0.0
> updated 1 package in 5.76s
> PS C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\loginLogout> npm i bcrypt
>
> bcrypt@3.0.6 install C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.10.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
> gyp ERR! find VS 
> gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
> gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
> gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.3.29411.108) found at:
> gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
> gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
> gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
> gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
> gyp ERR! find VS - not found
> gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
> gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
> gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
> gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
> gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:344:14)
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:365:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
> gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\safras\\Desktop\\authentication\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\safras\\Desktop\\authentication\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" 
> "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt
> gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
> gyp ERR! not ok
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
> --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding
> --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
> node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\safras\\Desktop\\authentication\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
> Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
> --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\safras\Desktop\authentication\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding
> --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
> npm WARN hapi-auth-basic@5.0.0 requires a peer of hapi@>=17.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN authentication@1.0.0 No description
> npm WARN authentication@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!enter code here
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\safras\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-18T06_35_24_418Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)

This is probably because you are not ysing a stable version of node. Check the docs on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

> `node-gyp` only works with stable/released versions of node. Since the `bcrypt` module uses `node-gyp` to build and install, you'll need a stable version of node to use bcrypt. If you do not, you'll likely see an error that starts with:
>
> `gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead`

Answer (score 2):

try to uninstall bcrypt and install bcryptjs

```
npm install --save bcryptjs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt
```

Comment: Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

**if you want bcrypt than**

```
npm install --build-from-resource
```

if above command doesnt fix your issue than it could be issue with fsevents   **((only if you are using it))**   so for this run

```
npm install fsevents
```

*if yet problem persist than it is issue with your node version and grpc version please [click here for more info](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/releases/tag/grpc%401.20.2)*